# php zf2 select where clause with SQL function

Tags: php, select, zend-framework2, where-clause, predicate

I need to compare DATE format from a DATETIME.

Prior ZF 2.3.5, the following code was working fine:

```
    $select->where('DATE(arrival_date) <= DATE(NOW())');
    $select->where('DATE(departure_date) >= DATE(NOW())');
    $select->where('enable = true');
```

With ZF 2.4.2+ it does not work anymore and produce the following error:

**Cannot inherit previously-inherited or override constant TYPE_IDENTIFIER from interface Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateInterface**

I have tried the following (without error). The problem is that "arrival_date" is a DATETIME format, and I need to compare with a DATE only.

```
    $where = new Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
    $where->lessThanOrEqualTo('arrival_date', date('Y-m-d'));
    $where->greaterThanOrEqualTo('arrival_date', date('Y-m-d'));
    $where->equalTo('enable', true);
    $select->where($where);
```

Ideally, this code should work, but it does not:

```
        $select->where(new Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('DATE(arrival_time) <= ?', 'DATE(NOW())'));
```

I am lost, any idea ?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you've mentioned all the details of the business?

Comment: Maybe the version of PHP I am using: 5.3.28

Comment: Works well with php 5.6

Comment: try using $where->addPredicate(new Expression('DATE(arrival_time) <= ?', 'DATE(NOW())'));

Comment: You set the \DateTime object's time properties to 0. setTime(0,0,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Expression like this:

```
    $select->where(
        array(
            new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression("DATE(arrival_date) <= DATE(NOW())")
        )
    );
```

No need of ? like you tried. With ? you params will be escaped and it won't work with an expression. Only with params, like a PHP datetime or something like this.

Tested with 2.4.2

Comment: I have accepted this answer for 2 reasons: 1st, it looks like PHP 5.3 was causing the issue. And 2nd, because it helps me to simplify the code by removing the "?". Now aother question came: why 5.3 makes the issue ? Does ZF 2.4.x not compatible with this version ? By the way, This is a Synology running PHP 5.3

Comment: Well, 2.4 is compatible with PHP 5.3 [link](http://framework.zend.com/blog/zend-framework-2-4-0-released.html) ... I don't think the problem is with PHP 5.3... I think it's because using ? the parameters are being escaped and you don't want this. --- the result SQL with ? will be: DATE(arrival_date) <= 'DATE(NOW())' ... see?

Comment: And one more thing... after 2.4, they introduced the Literal type, which is escaped. So, when you use a String on WHERE clause like this:     `$select->where('DATE(departure_date) >= DATE(NOW())');` ZF2 will use Literall instead of Expression, so it will be escaped. And you want an Expression....

Comment: Yes I know about ZF2 and 5.3 compatibility. But again. the code which is working before and not after ZF2.4 is the first one in my question (3 first line of code). So there is no '?'. So I am back to the root question.....