# php zf2 multiple where

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2, where-clause

I raise a question sometime ago: [php zf2 select where clause with SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165818/php-zf2-select-where-clause-with-sql-function)

But I am back because I'm still getting the same issue. I may be "stupid" but I really don't understand why and its getting me frustrated not being able to achieve the goal of a too simple SQL query.

This is my initial query which was working fine before ZF 2.3.5:

```
$select->where('(("' . $from . '" >= start_date AND "' . $from . '" < end_date ) OR ("' . 
$to . '" > start_date AND "' . $to . '" <= end_date ) OR ("' . 
$from . '" < start_date AND "' . $to . '" > start_date ))');
```

With ZF 2.4.9 I am getting the following:

**Cannot inherit previously-inherited or override constant TYPE_IDENTIFIER from interface Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\PredicateInterface**

I have tried all what I can do and even having a very small and simple clause. It still give me the above error:

```
$select->where(array(new Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression("start_date <= $from")));
$select->where("start_date <= $from");
$select->where("`start_date` <= $from");
$select->where("`s`.`start_date` <= $from");
$select->where("`s`.`start_date` <= " . $from);
$select->where("`s`.`start_date` <= '" . $from. "'");
```

I would really appreciate your help to understand what's going on, and how to get ride of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$select = new Select();
$select->where->addPredicates(array(
    new Predicate\Operator(
        'start_date',
        Predicate\Operator::OP_LTE,
        $from
    ),
    new Predicate\Operator(
        'end_date',
        Predicate\Operator::OP_GT,
        $from
    ),
));
```

More info there http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#zend-db-sql-where-zend-db-sql-having

Or this is more simple

```
$select->where(array(
    'start_date <= ?' => $from,
    'end_date > ?' => $from
));
```